# Warp/arc text shows original text too

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I have created text in Illustrator that I want to show in an arc'ed format.  I selected the text and then chose Effect/warp then I chose the type of arc I wanted.  So far so good.  The text shows as arc'ed BUT it also shows in a straight line underneath the arc'ed text.

Can someone please tell me how to do this without ending up with two sets of the same text?

[image: Screen Shot using Illustrator 18.0]

Comment: Didn't you make a second instance of the text object? Or could it be that it's the actual non-transformed object that you're seeing when you hover over the object? Welcome to GDSE!

Comment: You might also want to  tell us what version of Illustrator you are using.

Comment: Thanks all for the offers to help!  I've posted a screen shot.  I'm using Illustrator 18.0.  Please don't yell at me if I didn't post this correctly; I'm learning.

Comment: Just turn off Smart Guides (`View > Smart Guides`)

Comment: Hi Scott,
We're probably not allowed to send "thank yous" but your help to me is greatly appreciated.  That fixed a nagging problem for me.  THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Simply disable Smart Guides (`View > Smart Guides`).

Smart Guides will show a highlight of the text when you hover over an envelope. Since the basis of the envelope is undistorted text, that's what you see. It's blue to indication is it *merely an on screen highlight*. The blue won't actually print or be present when saving/exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving your cursor away and deselect the type? Please remember that Illustrator 'remembers' the original shape of the letters before the `arc` and will display that when you hover over the resulting shape or select it. Your text will export or print fine and only once.

If you `Object > Expand` the arc distortion, Illustrator will 'forget' the original shape, and the blue hover state will be the same shape. You might have to convert your type to outlines first for that to work, though.

Answer (score 1):

During editing you have the choice of Edit Envelope or Edit Contents

When editing contents the blue "base" text shows.

[image: Edit contents]

When editing the envelope it does not.

[image: Edit Envelope]